# HTML DIV height in IE

Tags: css, html

Here is a small piece of HTML.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="containerDiv" style="background-color:red; height: 200px">
        <div id="topDiv" style="background-color:green">
            <input type="button">1</input>
        <div>
        <div id="textAreaDiv" style="background-color:blue;width:100%; height:100%;">
            <textarea style="width:100%; height:100%;">123</textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="bottomDiv" style="background-color:purple">
            <input type="radio" name="Milk" value="Milk">Milk</input>
            <input type="radio" name="Butter" value="Butter">Butter</input>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do it to make textAreaDiv.height be containerDiv.height - (topDiv.height + bottomDiv.height). This works perfectly in Chrome, but not in IE9. In IE9 the textarea's height is about two character's height. Any idea how to get this to work in IE9 the same as in Chrome?

Here is a screen cap of what I am getting:
http://postimage.org/image/bfn6bsalv/

**UPDATE**
Here is a solution with javascript, but I would still like a purely CSS solution

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {          
            var textHeight = $('#containerDiv').height() - ($('#topDiv').height() + $('#bottomDiv').height());          
            $('#textBox').height(textHeight);
        });
    </script>
    <div id="containerDiv" style="background-color:red; height: 400px">
        <div id="topDiv" style="background-color:green;height:25px;">
            <input type="button">1</input>
        </div>
        <div id="textAreaDiv" style="background-color:blue;width:100%;">            
            <textarea id="textBox" style="width:100%;">123</textarea>           
        </div>
        <div id="bottomDiv" style="background-color:purple;height:25px;">
            <input type="radio" name="Milk" value="Milk">Milk</input>
            <input type="radio" name="Butter" value="Butter">Butter</input>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe just give all the inner DIVs a specific height each which adds up to the containg DIV's 200px? Then give the textarea the same height as it's parent DIV (remembering to take into account padding and borders. Hopefully you're also using a css reset file to get rid of all margins/padding before starting?

Comment: Cant do that because this is the generated html for custom asp.net control. So the user will set the containerDiv height and width and all the other divs should resize accordingly.

Comment: I know you said that Chrome renders it correctly but I'm not seeing what you're describing. [For me](http://jsfiddle.net/4H4bL/), the only difference between Chrome and IE9 is that Chrome's `textarea` is a couple pixels shorter. Correct me if I'm wrong, I think what you're trying to accomplish is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4H4bL/1/), but without setting the exact pixel height.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok - I updated the HTML. Paste that code in a file and look at it in Chrome and IE9. By the way, I think Fiddle does not render that html correctly. Create a new .html file and open it in Chrome/EI9. The problem with your solution is that are you hardcoding the textarea height. ContainerDiv is actually the container for a custom control whose height/width the user will be able to set accordingly. For example <asp:MilkButtonControl id="ID" Height="350px"/>. That will render containerDiv with height of 350px. This is why I need the textarea to not be a hardcoded value

Comment: I get that you don't want a hardcoded value. That's why I mentioned it in my comment. I also didn't propose a solution, I wanted to know the problem.

Comment: I updated post with screen cal link of my Chrome and IE of the same page

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you found something that worked. I wanted to let you know I see why it didn't work. Your code isn't valid. The closing tag for `topdiv` is missing the forward slash.